# Find Joomla module name in a Joomla website

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-module

My Joomla web page has some content that I want to remove (placed in only one page). It was placed using a module, but my site has large number of modules and I can't find which module it is. Is there any way to find module by filtering the page (menu) it placed ? It's a custom HTML module. Help me to find the module name.

Comment: I tried to find it using inspect element feature in google chrome and  firebug in Firefox.But I was unable to find it.

Comment: Do you know in which kind of module is the content ?

Comment: I think it is a custom HTML module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way we do this is searching the content field in the modules table in phpMyAdmin.

If you don't have access to phpMyAdmin, then check open then you can override the layout of the custom HTML module and print the ID of the module there. You can do this by adding the following code:

```
echo($module->id);
```

in the file `/templates/your-template/html/mod_custom/default.php` . If that file doesn't exist, then you should copy it from `modules/mod_custom/tmpl/default.php` (you should create the directory structure under the `/templates/your-template/html` folder if it doesn't already exist).

Answer (score 1):

If it's a custom HTML module, one simple solution is to install the useful [DB Replacer component](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/dbreplacer) (a freemium, free version is enough) and do a research in Tables : __modules and Field : content

Answer (score 1):

go to the module manager and use the filtering tabs on the left. filter type custom HTML, also filter type published, also filter position. If you don't know the position go to template manger and click the little eye and that will show you the module positions

Answer (score 1):

Short of looking for it manually in the database:

Find your home page menu item in the menu editor, you should see a "Module Assignment" tab which will display all modules and whether they are configured to be displayed on all pages or are targetting the current link.